# Angular2, How to reload a component only once?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I have two component `component A` and `component B`,

In component A, I post a HTTP request to a server and get a response with status="success". On `success` I navigate with `queryParams` of status='success' to component B.

In component B,  I will check in constructor() if I got `queryParam's` value as "success" then I want to reload it only once and redirect to next component C.

I've used `location.reload()` but I end up reloading component B again and again.

Is there any solution for that?

```
Component A
.subscribe(result => {
    if(result.status == 'success'){
        this.router.navigate(['/componentB'],{queryParams:{response: result.status}});
                                         }

component B    constructor(){
   this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
       (queryParam: any) => this.response = queryParam['response']);
     if(this.response == 'success'){
            this.route.navigate(['/componentC']);
            window.location.reload();
   }
```

}

Comment: What is component B's function? Have you got any code we can look at?

Comment: Is that all that component B does? If so can't you just navigate straight to C if "success", from what I can see B is an unnecessary step.

Comment: but for some reason i used to reload a component B and get result.status form params .

Comment: `window.location.reload();` is really not required if you load component with lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to component C and then navigate to the component that you want to reload. //the second parameter `_skipLocationChange=true` to avoid that url in back button

```
this.route.navigateByUrl('/componentC', true);
```